# How to classify the word “faire” in “tout faire”?

Tags: grammaire, sens, pronoms

In the sentence

> Ils savent tout faire.

what is the word *faire*? Is it a noun, as in *They know everything*, or a verb,  as in *They know (how to) do everything*?

Also, *tout* is singular masculine, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes **faire** is a verb and *tout* is singular masculine but it does not really matter here. The translation would be "They know how to do everything" or "They are able to do everything", "They can do everything" ...